# Delete top 3 rows from xls using excel.interop.object library

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am using excel.interop.object library 9.0 to manipulate my xls file in c#

If suppose i have a xls that have 5 sheets. All sheets having some rows.

I am using following code to delete top 2 rows from each sheet in my xls

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(mstrFilePath, 1, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, null, false);
        try
        {
            Excel.Sheets excelWorkSheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets;                
            foreach (Excel.Worksheet work in excelWorkSheet)
            {
                Excel.Range range = work.get_Range("A1", "A3");
                Excel.Range entireRow = range.EntireRow; // update
                for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    entireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);                       
                }                  
            }
            //excelWorkbook.Close(false, mstrFilePath, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            excelApp.Quit();
        }
```

But it is misbehaving deleting 2 rows from sheet 3 and not deleting any rows from any other sheet.

what went wrong here ?

Comment: THe first thing: You catch an exception but don't do anything with it. I'm pretty sure we get an exception here.
Here's why:
You try to call entireRow.Delete three times on the same row object - but you deleted it before already. If the "EntireRow" command selects multiple rows you can omit the for loop. If it doesn't, change the loop to "foreach row as Range in entireRow.Rows -> row.Delete" (somewhat pseudo-code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove **for loop**(for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)) in your code it will work.

Your already selecting the range from A1 to A3(Three rows) .........

```
Excel.Range range = work.get_Range("A1", "A3");
```

So no need to loop once again for same Range like below.....

```
//for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
//{
    entireRow.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
//}
```